# The Realm of Cubic Repetition

Tags: cipher, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

{0,1,1}-{1,1,1}-{0,0,1}-{1,1,1}-{0,0,0}-{1,1,0}-{1,1,1}!

Welcome!   You have entered the **REALM OF CUBIC REPETITION**.

Messages passed through here undergo a drastic transformation. All their letters are converted by means of a so-called FPR-substitution and are thereby split up into three dimensions. In all three dimensions they can be either highlighted (1) or not-highlighted (0). Eight possibilities in total of which only the eight(h) is unique.

In case you don't understand how this substitution is carried out:
*take two steps back and be the first to take a gamble*.

Your only way out is to find the number hidden in the grid below. In order to do so, decrypt the message within and follow the instructions. START doesn't count, the other cells are numbered 1 to 36, going from left to right, top to bottom. As the substitution is not unique, the numbers next to and below the grid could be helpful in determining the correct decryption.

For the final part: to find the right cells you need to carry out an FPR-substitution of your own. The input for this will be the corresponding letters of the alphabet of the cell numbers (after 26 start with A again). If you've performed it correctly you will observe that only two cells match the description.

[image: Grid]

After you've decrypted all 36 cells in this grid and found the message, your answer should fit in the following square precisely:
[image: Square]

By now, you may realize something is wrong, i.e., the number you've just found doesn't actually exist in that form. Please provide the number in its correct form here: ( _ _ _ _ ); that will be your passcode to exit the realm of cubic repetition.

Good luck!

---

N.B.: Below you can find a text version of the grid:

```
            START
47-{0,0,0}-{0,0,1}-{0,0,1}
33-{0,0,1}-{0,0,1}-{1,1,1}
24-{1,0,0}-{0,0,1}-{0,1,1}
29-{1,0,0}-{0,0,1}-{0,0,1}
35-{0,1,1}-{1,0,0}-{0,0,0}
27-{1,1,1}-{0,0,0}-{0,0,1}
29-{0,0,0}-{1,1,0}-{1,0,1}
42-{0,0,1}-{0,1,1}-{0,0,1}
47-{0,1,1}-{0,0,0}-{1,0,0}
39-{1,1,1}-{0,1,1}-{0,0,0}
53-{0,0,1}-{1,0,1}-{0,0,0}
38-{0,0,1}-{0,0,0}-{0,0,1}
     138  -  170  -  135
```

Hint:

> A good place to start is to try and figure what the name of this substitution (it's an acronym) could stand for. An anagram of it can be found somewhere in this puzzle.

Hint 2:

> What word could the first line ("{0,1,1}-{1,1,1}-{0,0,1}-{1,1,1}-{0,0,0}-{1,1,0}-{1,1,1}!") spell?

Comment: Can you add some hints? It has been over 24 hours with no answers or comments.

Comment: @FrodCube: I added a hint. Hopefully this will get you started. Good luck!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The phrase

> REALM OF CUBIC REPETITION

is an anagram of

> FIBONACCI PRIME ROULETTE

which surely means that our three bits are

> Fibonacci or not?, prime or not?, red or black in roulette?.

Presumably these are applied to

> letter numbers, A=1, Z=26; this fits for the ones I have checked so far if indeed the initial exclamation is WELCOME.

This means that our letter-to-bits table looks like this:

> `A  1 1 0 1
>  B  2 1 1 0
>  C  3 1 1 1
>  D  4 0 0 0 
>  E  5 1 1 1
>  F  6 0 0 0
>  G  7 0 1 1
>  H  8 1 0 0 
>  I  9 0 0 1
>  J 10 0 0 0
>  K 11 0 1 0
>  L 12 0 0 1
>  M 13 1 1 0
>  N 14 0 0 1
>  O 15 0 0 0
>  P 16 0 0 1
>  Q 17 0 1 0
>  R 18 0 0 1
>  S 19 0 1 1
>  T 20 0 0 0
>  U 21 1 0 1
>  V 22 0 0 0
>  W 23 0 1 1
>  X 24 0 0 0
>  Y 25 0 0 1
>  Z 26 0 0 0`

so the bits-to-letters table looks like

> `000 DFJOTVXZ
>  001 ILNPRY
>  010 KQ
>  011 GSW
>  100 H
>  101 AU
>  110 BM
>  111 CE`

and the reason for the "eight(h)" is that

> the only "unique letter" is H, which is the eighth letter of the alphabet.

Now let's attack the cipher. It's an obvious guess that

> the row and column "marginals" are sums of letter numbers

and in fact they turn out to be. By a combination of inference from these sums and plausible-word spotting (you can find the details in an older revision of this answer, if you care; credit to @elias for finding the first word) the message turns out to be

> TRIPLE HIGHLIGHTED ROMANS IS THE SOLUTION.

There are several roughly equally plausible ways to interpret this. I think the intended one (which took me a while to think of; the edit history contains my other attempts) is this:

> The numbers (letter indices) that get three highlights according to the FPR rule are 3 and 5. The cells numbered 3 and 5 contain, respectively, I and L. Interpreting this as a Roman numeral yields 49 (a square number, which I think is all that was meant by fitting precisely into the square). But the Romans didn't actually write 49 as IL. They wrote it as XLIX, which is therefore the passcode we need.

Comment: Brilliant!  +1 Are we supposed to find a number from it? Also, I am wondering if we need a letter from each set there or all the letters from each set?

Comment: rows 3-4-5 stand definitely for 'highlight'

Comment: @elias yes (I was figuring that out at the same time as you :-)).

Comment: first two rows say 'triple'

Comment: First row could be LIFT?

Comment: @elias Plausible. Have you proved this? If so I'll edit it in; if not I'll see what I can deduce myself and see whether I agree :-).

Comment: i did not exclude other solutions, but 2nd row is PLE/LPE/NNE/NPC/PNC for sure, and TRI fits the sums and bitmasks of the first row nicely.

Comment: also, I think it is possible, that there are actually numbers in the range up to 36 used (OP speaks about numbers larger than 26), which opens up new possibilities instead of 'NGN'

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. Though 42 isn't *very* large...

Comment: For the last I thought it was "BER" because it fits well and second last could have been "*NUM"

Comment: NGN does not seem to be right to me. with N=14 and G=7 the sum is 35, not 42.

Comment: aha, crappy arithmetic. That's good news.

Comment: however, I cannot see any solution for that line. maybe an error in the puzzle? @Levieux, could you please doublecheck the 8. row?

Comment: I think I do. See the current state of my answer.

Comment: oh, looks like there are slightly different coloring setups of the roulette numbers.

Comment: nice work! but what is the solution then? :)

Comment: Still thinking about that. And now I have to be AFK for the next half hour or so. Perhaps someone else will swoop in, figure out the ending, and get the coveted green checkmark...

Comment: Isn't C a triple highlight?

Comment: May be the highlighted triples mean - All **red** 1's which gives 3 E's(2,6,10 th rows).So the answer is 2-6-1-0 I guess

Comment: C is a roman numeral which is a triple-highlight (Fibonacci & prime & red), but does it have the form _ _ _ _ ?

Comment: d'oh, indeed C is a triple highlight. I don't know what I was thinking. E isn't a Roman numeral, though :-).

Comment: Anyway, really truly AFK for a bit now.

Comment: I thought about that, but why 3 and 5 and not 29 and 31 (26+3, 26+5), since the question explicitly tells us to loop back to A after 26?

Comment: Because those don't have Roman numerals in them. Er, wait, except that 31 does; it has an L. So I'm not sure; it may be a mistake, either mine or Levieux's. My other leading theory was that since C is the unique Roman-numeral letter that gets three highlights, we needed to look at cells 3 and 29. But that falls down because 29 doesn't have a Roman numeral in it. (Also, this feels like the word "Roman" is doing two separate jobs.)

Comment: Great job! I can see now that the "Roman" part might have been misdirecting a bit. It was actually redundant, since both triple highlighted cells contained Roman numbers. As for the "following square" part, this hints towards the fact that after going through all 36 cells the answer should be the square that follows (49 follows 36). Anyway, well done!

Comment: Thanks. Fun puzzle. I think ffao's objection is that cells 3+26 and 5+26 should be considered as triple-highlighted too because of what the question says about wrapping back to A after Z. I don't see how that's wrong; what am I missing? (I think that just removing the bit about wrapping would fix this problem, though it might damage the earlier stages by making it more obvious that the FPR thing works via letter numbers.)

Comment: I don't understand the "take two steps back and be the first to take a gamble." sentence. What does it mean?

Comment: It's a cryptic hint at what FPR stands for. "take two steps back" is meant to remind you of the Fibonacci sequence; "be the first" alludes to "prime"; "take a gamble" to roulette.

Answer (score 4):

Looks arbitrary, but since there is no attempt being made yet, here is what I assume...

> If we consider the first set of binaries = WELCOME! we get -
>  {0,1,1} = **W**
>  {1,1,1} = **E**
>  {0,0,1} = **L**
>  {1,1,1} = **C**
>  {0,0,0} = **O**
>  {1,1,0} = **M**
>  {1,1,1} = **E**

So,

> The table should look like
>  [image]

Comment: Your first step is indeed correct, but simply plugging these letters into the table below doesn't work, because the substitution is, as mentioned, not unique.
Your next step should be to figure out what the substitution does precisely. Having this first word deciphered might prove helpful there.

Comment: I think the {} were meant to acknowledge that those aren't necessarily the letters involved.

Answer (score 1):

Attacking based on hint 1:

> the acronym mentioned might be an anagram of 'REALM OF CUBIC REPETITION'. For me the word starting with P cries out to be PERMUTATION, but I cannot make too much sense of the rest. 'FIBO PERMUTATION RECICLE' seems to be too much of a stretch with its typo.

Comment: The most obvious candidate phrases in the puzzle for anagramming are REALM OF CUBIC REPETITION, as you say; FOLLOWING SQUARE PRECISELY; and maybe FOR THE FINAL PART. (Because each contains F, P, and R, and each reads a little oddly.) I've fed all of these to the Internet Anagram Server and not found any plausible-sounding anagrams. (Which doesn't prove much.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, how about 'take two steps back and be the first to take a gamble'?

Comment: Well, "two steps back" suggests Fibonacci (a thought I guess you had too from your FIBO) and you can actually get all of FIBONACCI out of r.o.c.r. You can in fact get FIBONACCI PERMUTE but what's left doesn't form a word starting with R.

Comment: The first mathematical treatments of gambling were, I think, by Fermat and Pascal, who have nice friendly initial letters :-), but I suspect this is a red herring.

Comment: aha! FIBONACCI PRIME ROULETTE must be it

Comment: hah! great finding!

Answer (score 0):

Is the puzzle accurate or have I not finished? I get:

> TRIPLE HIGHLIGHTED RFBUNS IS THE SOLUTION

for the cells

> (with S = 0,1,1. I think it should be 0,1,0). If I use the vertical >!addition instead of horizontal, ignoring the cells I don't understand, I >!can finagle DEMONS instead of RFBUNS, but this gives me no insight.

I have some ideas how to proceed from there, but they aren't giving me anything meaningful (to me), so I wanted to check my progress so far.

Thanks for the intricate puzzle!

Comment: S is 0,1,1. See my answer for (I'm 99% sure) the correct message.

Comment: In any case, at this point you have not finished. (Neither have I.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, Thanks -- your answer corrected my alphabet in a couple places. Still working...

Comment: (I now have what I believe to be a complete answer, FYI.)

Comment: (Except that ffao has raised an objection, which is not without merit.)